# Can I go back to my old playthrough on Forgotten Hourglass activation?

Tags: deemo

I am met with a completely reset and new storyline after I clicked the Forgotten Hourglass in Alice's Room. I have finished Deemo 2.0 and reached the credits. Is it possible to go back to the old playthrough?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a choice to go to "main story," "forgotten hours," and "cancel" when you click the hourglass.

Answer (score -1):

You must get the tree to 50m and the stairs to 100%. To get all the songs/charts/photos do this 3 times more.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve your old playthrough anymore?